# Push calendar event to Office 365 in asp.Net

Tags: office365

Basically, My Knowledge level in Office 365 at Beginning level.

I have developed asp.net calendar application with email address..
using that application I can mark my leave days in  that calendar.What I wanna do is push the calendar event days to Office 365 using may email..
Then my office mail group can see my leave days in Office 365 calendar..

can anyone help me please...?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations